# Batch File: If registry key's data is equal to

Tags: batch-file, registry

I'm trying to make a .bat toggler for certain Explorer settings. To do this I need the batch file to query the Registry key's data and then set the key accordingly. For example, in ActionScript 3 or JavaScript it would be something along the lines of this:

```
if (HideFileExt == "00000000"){
    HideFileExt = 00000001;
else {
    HideFileExt = 00000000;
}
```

This way, every time it runs it will set the key's data to be the opposite of what it currently is - a toggler.

I have Google-d this extensively and after quite a long time of chopping up and splicing multiple examples, I eventually got this:

```
REG QUERY HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v HideFileExt /t REG_DWORD /d 00000000

if errorlevel 1 (
    echo Num 1
) else (
    echo Num 2
)

rem The "echo Num"s are there just so that I could eventually figure out what the errorlevel does
```

which returns the error:

```
ERROR: Invalid syntax.
Type "REG QUERY /? for usage.
num 1
```

If I remove the `/d 00000000` from the `REG QUERY` then it returns the accurate data value of the key without error. I have also tried it with `/d 0`, `/d 0x0` and `/d 0x00000000` and they didn't work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Answer from Dennis is correct, but I thought id paste the whole batch file so you can see it all working.

```
REG QUERY "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v "HideFileExt" | Find "0x0"
IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 goto turnoff
If %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 goto turnon

goto end
:turnon
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v 

HideFileExt /t REG_DWORD /f /D 1
goto end

:turnoff
REG ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced" /v 

HideFileExt /t REG_DWORD /f /D 0
goto end

:end
@exit
```

Comment: Thanks for this, great solution. One question - is there any particular reason you used `goto:end` then `exit` instead of `goto:eof`?

Comment: I just wanted to update that this doesn't work as is, not for me at least. I had to make sure the `reg` commands were on a single line; splitting each one into two made the script fail for me. From the votes and lack of followup comments that this answer got, I'm guessing other people's mileage varied, or I was just missing something. Either way, thanks again.

Comment: Gives syntax error on line 2. You must execute reg query command on the same line and remove double quotes from "HideFileExt"

Answer (score 7):

The `/d` switch doesn't do what you think. It is a modifier to the `/f` switch, which is used to specify a search pattern. Unfortunately, `/v` already defines a search pattern, and they do not get along.

To check whether `HideFileExt` is set to `0`, you can pipe `reg`'s result to `find`:

```
reg query HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced /v HideFileExt | find "0x0"
if errorlevel 1 echo "HideFileExt is 0"
if errorlevel 0 echo "HideFileExt is not 0"
```

Comment: Thank you Dennis. Your answer was good too, but I felt I should award it to SmithMart as he has significantly less points than yourself and he answered in more detail. But thank you all the same! :)

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 this is how you can do it:

In cmd write:

```
powershell -executionpolicy unrestricted C:\path_to_powershell_file.ps1
```

Make a powershell file with the following code and save it (Example to check if chrome is default browser):

```
$path = 'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\.html\UserChoice'
$value = 'ProgId'
$path_verif = Get-itemProperty -Path $path | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $value
if($path_verif -match 'chrome'){
    Write-Host "Chrome is default browser" -ForegroundColor Green

} else{
    Write-Host "Chrome is NOT default browser. -ForegroundColor Red 
}
```