# Windows - file extensions manipulations

Tags: windows, cmd

Im trying to do 2 simple things using the command line.
I want to create a batch file that runs cmd commands and does the following:

a) Confirm open after download option to certain types of file (.pdf,.doc etc).

b) Always show extension option to certain types of file (.pdf,.doc etc).

I can't find the way of doing it,
Thank you for your help.
Ben

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [reg command](http://www.computerhope.com/reg.htm) to change these settings in the registry. However, it won't take effect until the user logs out and in again.

a) The Internet Explorer "Always ask before opening this type of file" options are stored under:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\AttachmentExecute\{0002DF01-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/905703

b) I don't think you can control showing extensions for individual file types. You can only control whether extensions for *all* known file types are shown or not, using:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\HideFileExt

See the following stackoverflow question. The answer happens to have an example of the reg command with this exact registry setting:
[Batch File: If registry key's data is equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315289/batch-file-if-registry-keys-data-is-equal-to)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. One thing i don't understand: if i want to set 20 types of files to show "Always ask before opening this type of file" how do i do it using the reg editor ?