# Query the data of a reg key value and use "goto" and "if" to base output on said value

Tags: powershell, batch-file, registry

Hi I am trying to create a batch file which queries a registry key and based on its value, a specific program is launched.

I have tried various combinations from the internet, but I cant seem to get the correct behaviour.

Basically, the script will check the regkey which defines what the current DPI is. Based on the value, one of two programs will run (PowerShell scripts) which in turn runs an InternetExplorer.Application window with specific size restraints.

Sources:

- [REG QUERY use in a batch file with IF/THEN](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20674876/REG-QUERY-use-in-a-batch-file-with-IF-THEN.html)
- [Batch File: If registry key's data is equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9315289/batch-file-if-registry-keys-data-is-equal-to)

What I have got so far is this:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set "Key=HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics"
set Type=REG_DWORD
set Value=AppliedDPI

set Data=
for /f "tokens=2,3" %%a in ('reg query %Key% /v %Value% 2^>NUL ^| find /i "%Value%"') do (
 set TestType=%%a
 set Data=%%b
)
if /i "%Data%"=="0x60" goto Data_96
if /i "%Data%"=="0xc0" goto Data_192
if /i not "%TestType%"=="%Type%" goto :Data_Missing
goto Data_Undefined

:Data_96
echo Data is "%Data%".
goto 96

:Data_192
echo Data is "%Data%".
goto 192

:Data_Missing
echo Key or value not found.
goto leave

:Data_Undefined
echo No action for data "%Data%" defined.
goto leave

:96
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File somescript1.ps1
goto leave

:192
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File somescript2.ps1
goto leave

:leave
```

But it just doesn't work. Keep getting "Key or Value not found".
Other samples I have tried end up loading both scripts.
I have obviously set something wrong, but not sure what it is.

Comment: You need to put quotes around your %key% variable in your REG QUERY. `reg query "%Key%" /v %Value%`

Comment: Thanks for reply @Squashman. Unfortunarely this now outputs another error: '┬áset' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: @Squashman Thank you. With your help and also answering my own following question ('┬áset'  was due to 'set' having a space before it) I have now got it to work! Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any spaces in your set commands that would cause a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here, for your information, is a script which should do the same thing:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "PSS="
For /F "Tokens=1,3" %%A In (
    'Reg Query "HKCU\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics" /v AppliedDPI'
) Do If /I "%%A"=="AppliedDPI" (If %%B Equ 96 Set PSS=somescript1.ps1
    If %%B Equ 192 Set PSS=somescript2.ps1)
If defined PSS powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File "%PSS%"
```

It uses that fact that the operators do not care if the values are hex or decimial.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I have Compiled the script now, compiled and wrapped it into an installer. So as it works, I wont be messing with it for the foreseeable future. Appreciate your time though.

Comment: That's no problem, as I said it was for your information. _BTW, if you post your completed script in your own answer, there is no reason why you cannot mark that answer as correct_.

Answer (score 0):

With the solution from @Squashman and also realising my own mistake of having spaces before my "set" commands, The script now works as intended.